# Prevent deleting newly typed url's

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, internet-explorer-8, autocomplete

Can someone please let me know how i can prevent a limited user in windows 7 from deleting newly typed url's in internet explorer or any other browser by just pointing to the url and pressing the "delete" button. This effectively means the user should be able to type any new url but should not be able to delete it. The user should be able to see the url when he next opens the browser. 
The reason i need this job done is to let the user know that his internet usage is monitored. Please also note that i do not wish to use any internet filter or any other means of recording web activity, except the method i have precisely mentioned above. In short, i wish to monitor user activity from the "url bar only".

Answer (score 0):

You can disable users from deleting the browser history by folling this Microsoft Technet article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349812.aspx

You need to type gpedit.msc to open the Group Policies Editor in the Run window of the user and turn off the values for deleting browsing history.

To quote from the above mentioned website:

> If you don’t want users to be able to delete their browsing history,
>   form data, or passwords, you can enable the following group policy
>   settings located in both Computer Configuration\Administrative
>   Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\ and User
>   Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet
>   Explorer: Turn off “Delete Browsing History” Functionality Turn off
>   “Delete Forms” Functionality Turn off “Delete Passwords” Functionality